# No clutch fluid flows out through the slave cylinder bleed valve and no resistance in clutch

Tags: clutch, bleeding, clutch-cylinder

I have a CORONA 1986 Sedan (Model L-KT147V-TXKDS).

The issue is when I tried to take the car out for a drive the clutch gave in. Meaning the clutch just went to the floor without any resistance. Following are the observations,

1. No external oil leaks observed in the Master or the Slave Cylinders.
2. I removed the bleed nut in the slave cylinder but no fluid came out even though the master reservoir is full.
3. The clutch fork is engaged by the slave cylinder and not returning back or disengaging.

Can someone please give some insights on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The master cylinder has failed.

Comment: Does your clutch use the the dot4 from your brake fluid tank,
Sounds like you need to bleed it to find the cause